# How to make Matlab editor open a new script as a tab by default, instead of a new window?

Tags: matlab, tabs, preferences

I'm used to using tabs rather than having many new windows open. I've recently changed (work) computers and now whenever I open an old script or start writing a new one it opens a new instance of the matlab editor. The question is, does anybody know how to change the default to a new tab within the same editor? (hope that makes sense).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open 2 scripts or more. On one of the editor windows press the circled triangle (I am sure it has a proper name):
[image]

Select Dock All in Editor.
The files should appear as tabs docked to the matlab desktop.
You can now undock the editor using the same button (you should undock the editor, not a specific file)
Any file you open now should be in a new tab.